# high Stock chart selecting inputEnabled:true is not working smoothly

Tags: highcharts, jscript

I am using High Stock Chart I read the API documentation which says if you do inputEnabled:true than you can select date range from same.

I tried same: [JS FIDDLE LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/aalok25/wkmkkwrr/)

```
rangeSelector: {
    selected: 1,
    inputEnabled:true
}
```

Its Working only after when I click several times in container div.
Its not working first time I am coming and selecting it.

Is there a way I can make it smooth as given in high chart demo link
[high stock demo link](http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/column)

Happening for older version of firefox

Comment: Works fine for me in FireFox 34.0.5. Which browser are you using?

Comment: Firefox 32.0.1
Its working for me but after a very long delay

Comment: @Sundeep I want to make it smooth as its happening in demos link

Comment: No idea why the behavior is such. If you see the same behavior in the [high charts demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/stock/demo/column/) too, then I suggest you upgrade your browser. Test in other browsers as well to see if it is consistent.

Comment: @Sundeep Ya its default in fiddle link of their demo also.'

Comment: @Sundeep Looks like a browser problem only. In chrome its  smooth

Comment: Which OS you have? Bacause I also cannot replicate it